# Input button moving on page refresh?

Tags: html, css, submit

I have a login form and with that I have a custom image button. For some reason, if the page is refreshed or reloaded, it will sometimes be moved down a line and mess up formatting. If the page is refreshed again, it goes back to normal. This happens over and over again. I have no idea what is causing it. Anyway, here is my form and css for it. It is labeled as value=login. Also the entire form is in the class "login_box.

login form code:

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="user" maxlength="30" size="16px" value="<?php echo $form->value("user"); ?>"></td><td><?php echo $form->error("user"); ?></td></tr>
                            <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="pass" maxlength="30" size="15px" value="<?php echo $form->value("pass"); ?>"></td><td><?php echo $form->error("pass"); ?></td></tr>
                            <input type="hidden" name="sublogin" value="1">
                            <div class="button"><input type="image" src="images/login.png"  width="26px" onmouseout="this.src='images/login.png'" onmouseover="this.src='images/loginhover.png'" onmouseout="t value="Login"></div>
                            <br><input type="checkbox" name="remember" <?php if($form->value("remember") != ""){ echo "checked"; } ?>>
                            <font size="2" color="#BDBDBD"> Remember Me 
                            <div class="forgot"><font size="2"><a href="forgotpass.php">Forgot Password?</a></font></div>
                            <div class="New"><br><a href="register.php">New Member? Register Now!</a></div>
                            </form>
```

and the css for the entire form, the button is the .button class:

```
.login_box {
    float:left;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-right:-590px;
    margin-left:35px;
    list-style: none;

}

.login_box  li {

}

.login_box li a {
    color:#BDBDBD;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding-left:60px;

    padding:0px;

}

.logged_in {
    background-color:#585858;
    border:2px solid#FFFFFF;
    width:308px;
    height:55px;
    margin-left:-5px;
}

.welcome {
    color:#B40404;
    font-size:22px;
    text-decoration:underline;
    font-family:"Rockwell";
    padding-left:10px;
}

.account {
    list-style:none;
    display:inline;
    padding:0px;
    font-size:13px;
    text-decoration:underline;
    margin-left:10px

}

.forgot {
    display:inline;
    padding-left:38px
}

.New {

    padding-left:38px;
    font-size:16px;
    margin-top:-18px
}

.button {
    display:inline;
    float:right;
    margin-left:1px;
    position:absolute 


}

.register_box {
    float: center;
    padding-left:100px
}
```

Comment: Does anything change between successive refreshes? For example, do you resize the window or run server-side code?

Comment: it doesn't do it as much now, only out of like 10 refreshes it happens once or twice. Still weird though.

Comment: Stuff doesn't just magically break. There has to be something changing. Think hard: it could be the most trivial thing you would never think of.

Comment: Can you send us a link to a live example?

Comment: unfortunately, it is on my local host... So I can't link you guys

Answer (score 1):

Your table structure has problems, there are closing tags without opening tags and there are `<td>` elements outside `<tr>` elements (assuming a couple of them are before/after the code you've posted.